# Types of conditionals: "If ... I would be ... now" / "If I die(d) tomorrow I would be alright"

Tags: conditionals

Could someone help me figure out what kind of conditionals these sentences fit into? (I've been looking at conditionals [here](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/conditionals.html).)

- "If I had taken that bus I would be safe and warm right now."— it starts out like a third conditional but it doesn’t end with “have + participle” (as in the example “If I had studied harder I would have passed the exam”). So what is the rule for this example and which type of conditional does it fit into?
- “If I die tomorrow I’d be alright because I believe….” (It’s from song lyrics). Is "die"  correct here? Or is it “died”? Which type of conditional does this fit?

Comment: Logically, the second one should be _If I die tomorrow I will..._ or _if I died tomorrow I would..._

Comment: Personally, for the second, I'd vote for "If I were to die tomorrow I'd...". But song lyrics are given a lot of grace for poetic license; it's hardly the least grammatical thing ever put to music.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "If I had taken that bus I would be safe and warm right now."

This is correct.  It's what's known in some EFL/ESL textbooks as a "mixed conditional" or "mixed 2/3 conditional" because the "if" clause has a verb in the past perfect (as in the third conditional) but the consequence clause has the construction "would"+*bare infinitive* (as in the second conditional).

Like a third conditional, the "if" clause describes a condition that is in the past - a past unreal condition that was not met.  But like a second conditional, the consequence clause describes a consequence that is in the present (not a consequence in the past).

In the third conditional you'd say "If I had taken that bus I would have been safe and warm", but instead you want to express the fact that if you'd done things differently you'd be safe and warm *now*, so you use the mixed construction.  It's perfectly standard and perfectly logical.

> "If I die tomorrow I’d be alright because I believe…"

This, on the other hand, is badly worded.  It should be either "If I die tomorrow, I'll be all right..." (first conditional) or "If I died tomorrow, I'd be all right..." (second conditional).  (The form "If I were to die tomorrow, I'd be all right..." is also fine and is a variant of the second conditional. I use the spelling "all right" because in British English the spelling "alright" is sometimes considered nonstandard.)

Comment: Thank you very much for that explanation. Can you tell me about this sentence too?: "I'd be safe and warm if I was in LA" -- is this correct and second conditional? Could it also be "were" instead of "was"? Thanks again!

Comment: @JoannaRedman Yes, that's correct too and is a second conditional - and "were" would work as well. In formal usage, "were" is preferred, but most native speakers substitute "was" at least some of the time. ("People often say *if I was you* and *if it was up to me*, but the subjunctive is preferable in writing, especially any formal or academic prose." - https://www.lexico.com/grammar/when-to-use-the-subjunctive )

Comment: Thank you very much for your great answers! Do you know any resources online (or otherwise) that summarise the different kinds of conditionals along with the mixed ones too?

Comment: Also, for the subjunctive: can either of these be correct too?: "I was wondering if it was for a trip" and "I was wondering if it were for a trip". Thanks again, Joanna

Comment: You could try https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/conditionals-1 , https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/conditionals-2 , https://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/british-grammar/conditionals-if

Comment: If "was" is referring to the real past or is backshifted from the present, only "was" is possible, not "were". I don't think "were" could work in that sentence. If in doubt, it is better to stick with the non-subjunctive form.

Comment: Here's another example of a real past. Someone says to me "I'm certain that you were there on Saturday"; I reply "if I was there, I don't remember it". "Were" would be impossible because this is a real past. ("If I were there", sometimes also "was", is used for an unreal present/future; "if I had been there" is used for the unreal past; "if I am there" is the real present.)